# PHP: Why is my function validate_ip() undefined?

Tags: php, undefined

I get the error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function validate_ip()" and want to understand why.

The error comes when the function get_ip_address() calls the function validate_ip(). Both functions are in the same file and will be included by require_once. So why is the function "undefined"?

Or could the error have another cause?

Thank you in advance,
Matthias

```
/**
 * Get Ip Adddress
 * @return [varchar] [IP Address]
 */
protected function get_ip_address() 
{

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], ',') !== false) {
            $iplist = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            foreach ($iplist as $ip) {
                if (validate_ip($ip))
                    return $ip;
            }
        } else {
            if (validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];

    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}


 /**
 * Ensures an ip address is both a valid IP and does not fall within
 * a private network range.
 */
protected function validate_ip($ip)
{
    if (strtolower($ip) === 'unknown')
        return false;

    $ip = ip2long($ip);

    // if the ip is set and not equivalent to 255.255.255.255
    if ($ip !== false && $ip !== -1) {
        /** make sure to get unsigned long representation of ip
        * due to discrepancies between 32 and 64 bit OSes and
        * signed numbers (ints default to signed in PHP) 
        */
        $ip = sprintf('%u', $ip);
        // do private network range checking
        if ($ip >= 0 && $ip <= 50331647) return false;
        if ($ip >= 167772160 && $ip <= 184549375) return false;
        if ($ip >= 2130706432 && $ip <= 2147483647) return false;
        if ($ip >= 2851995648 && $ip <= 2852061183) return false;
        if ($ip >= 2886729728 && $ip <= 2887778303) return false;
        if ($ip >= 3221225984 && $ip <= 3221226239) return false;
        if ($ip >= 3232235520 && $ip <= 3232301055) return false;
        if ($ip >= 4294967040) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the complete Error-Log:

> [05-Dec-2018 21:37:07 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function validate_ip() in /home/www/crm3/clients/app/http/controllers/ProfileController.php:258
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /home/www/crm3/clients/app/http/controllers/ProfileController.php(135): ProfileController->get_ip_address()
>   1 /home/www/crm3/clients/app/http/controllers/ProfileController.php(72): ProfileController->update(Array)
>   2 /home/www/crm3/clients/builder/engine/Router.php(53): ProfileController->profileAction()
>   3 /home/www/crm3/clients/builder/engine/Router.php(42): Router->dispatch(Array)
>   4 /home/www/crm3/clients/builder/bootstrap.php(77): Router->route('profile', 'POST')
>   5 /home/www/crm3/clients/index.php(36): require_once('/home/www/crm3...')
>   6 {main}
>     thrown in /home/www/crm3/clients/app/http/controllers/ProfileController.php on line 258

edit: added error log

Comment: First thing i try when i have this kind of issues is to change the name if the function and call it by the new name. Can you please try jt?

Comment: How do you call it? How is `validate_ip` defined?

Comment: Are these inside a Class?

Comment: Correct me if am wring but protected functions can be accessed only within the class it resides in. If your two functions are not in same class, you will bit be able to call one from another.  Try putting them in a class... Thus changing the structure of your code or simply do away with the protected prefix

Comment: Yes, both functions are in my ProfileController class.

Comment: No, I tried to change the functionn name without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If these are methods inside the same class then you need to call `$this->validate_ip($ip)`.

If these are just functions in a file then you need to remove `protected` from the function declarations.

Comment: This doesn't have sense if you're outside a class. And, if they're on a class, the question are erroneous then.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto "the question are erroneous " --- how?

Comment: If the function are defined inside a class, this information should be specified on the question itself. Without these data you cannot provide a correct answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify when `$this` should be used and when `protected`should be removed.

Comment: Great! I changed "if (validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))" to "if ($this->validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))" Now it works very fine. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the function definition itself. You're defining your function as a "protected function".

A "protected" function, are a visibility keyword used in classes for define a function not accessible from outside the class itself. It doesn't have sense to use outside a class.

If you remove "protected" keyword from definition, you can call your function without any problem.

Comment: If it was a case they would have got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED)` not a runtime error

Comment: Yes, I tried this before posting here. But there is the same error too without "protected".